# Mavericks Server /Work group manager issues

Tags: macos, server.app, setup

I upgraded a test server running snow leopard to mavericks and then was having some weirdness so I decided to recreate my open directory, users and groups.

Server appears to be running and I am able to connect from a laptop /user

But... Work group manager does not see the users in Server except the server diradmin user, and there is a message at the top that says 
**"Viewing local directory /Local/Default. Not Authenticated."**

Now I'm assuming the problem is that I need to authenticate Work group manager but I don't see how...

Previously I did see my users but they were all grey'd out. I think that's when I decided to recreate my open directory, users and groups. but now I see nothing as I said.

Also I get a message from Work Group Manager **You are working in a directory node that is not visible to the network.**

I should mention,

HOST NAME is nserver.local

WORK GROUP MANAGER Version 10.9 (421)
SERVER Version 3.1.2 (1354517)

My users are all Local Network Users,
My server does not use a domain name, I intend to have shared user storage, VPN and perhaps calendar.

Any tips or ideas?

Thank!

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED FOR ME.

I don't recall seeing this before in Snow leopard (the interface was slightly different...), on the same line at the message "Viewing local directory /Local/Default. Not Authenticated." there is a small triangle --- clicking on this reveals a drop menu.

Select LDAPv3 from the list.  Then click on the lock at the far end of that bar. 
Authenticate as DIRADMIN and it works.